# JstlView forwarding request to dispatcher servlet instead of rendering the view(Spring boot + Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have set up an spring boot application and I am trying to run a simple mvc flow. But JstlView class is forwarding the request to render `/WEB-INF/views/jsp/login.jsp` to 'dispatcherServlet' and I am getting the following logs:-

```
2015-10-25 17:43:06.143 DEBUG 6181 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'login'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/jsp/login.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-10-25 17:43:06.143 DEBUG 6181 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Added model object 'username' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'login'
2015-10-25 17:43:06.146 DEBUG 6181 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/jsp/login.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'login'
2015-10-25 17:43:06.148 DEBUG 6181 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

My Application.java to run spring boot application:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.thinksmallgroup.projectmanager")
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet(), "*.do");
        return registration;
    }

    /**
     * main method to start the application.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            any arguments passed while running the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

My WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/", ".jsp");
        registry.order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

}
```

Controller:-

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    /**
     * @param name
     * @return String
     */
    @RequestMapping("/login.do")
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(required = false) String name) {

        return new ModelAndView("login", "username", "VIneet");
    }
```

My login.jsp:-

```html
<html>
  <head><title>Think Small Group</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Project Manager</h1>
    <p>Welcome ${username}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: My Project Structure]

Comment: I fail to understand what the problem is. What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Sorry if I was so confusing. Problem is that my jsp is not being rendered when I hit [http://localhost:8080/login.do], page comes blank. When I debugged it I saw that InternalSourceView is forward the request. I want to make it run, I googled a lot for this and tried as many possible solutions as I found. I hope my problem is clear now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSPs should be under src/main/webapp, not under src/main/resources.

Comment: I think the main point is that the path I am giving to view resolver must be at classpath. Isn't it?

Comment: @fabian Thanks for code editing

Comment: @JBNizet I tried moving '/WEB-INF/views/jsp/login.jsp' under 'src/main/webapp' but still blank screen is rendering. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you read http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations? Have you tried starting from the linked example?

Comment: Thanks for this link.. it simply means that I need to use war packaging. I missed that limitations part.